# Get string class method called on - Ruby/Crystal

Tags: crystal-lang

I've been extending the string class in Crystal to support a "center" method. I have made the ability to get width and height, and I have most of the other parts. I just want this:

```
class String
  def center
    (I::Terminal.get_size.col / 2).times do #Half of screen width
      print " "
    end
    #puts text that method was called on
  end
end
puts "text".center #I want to puts "text" after my spacing
```

Comment: `print self` at the commented line?

Comment: What does this have to do with [tag:ruby]? What is `I`? What is `Terminal`?

Comment: Is that a snippet from somewhere else?  does it work?

Comment: This does work. print self is the best way to do it. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need the `times` block. You can use `String#rjust` instead.

This code works in both Ruby and Crystal
(assuming you have the terminal width sorted out through `I::Terminal.get_size.col`)

```
class String
  def center(width = nil)
    width ||= I::Terminal.get_size.col
    half_width = (width / 2).to_i
    half_size = (self.size / 2).to_i
    self.rjust(half_width + half_size)
  end
end

puts "this is a nice text".center 80
```

I noticed you tagged this question as Crystal, but you ask about Ruby/Crystal - just in case you are using Ruby, know that you don't need it, since [it is already implemented](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/String.html#method-i-center).